# How to show config on Extremeware switch without pagination?

Tags: configuration, switch

When doing a `show config` how do you display the whole configuration without having it pause with a message saying to press space or Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
disable clipaging
```

Unless your firmware is too old to support that command.